# What is the Opensearch equivalent of the Elasticsearch config value index.mapping.total_fields.limit

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have an error in my Opensearch cluster: "Limit of total fields [1000] has been exceeded". I can see that this problem can be fixed in Elasticsearch by setting `index.mapping.total_fields.limit` to a higher value.

But looking in my Opensearch cluster settings, this setting doesn't seem to be there.  I tried modifying it using Terraform but I got this error:

```
 Error: ValidationException: Unrecognized advanced option 'index.mapping.total_fields.limit' passed in advancedOptions.
│ 
│   with module.opensearch.aws_elasticsearch_domain.aws_opensearch,
│   on ../modules/opensearch/main.tf line 27, in resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "aws_opensearch":
│   27: resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "aws_opensearch" {
```

I can't find any mention of how to adjust the mapping total fields limit in the Opensearch documentation for our cluster version 1.1

Does anyone know the name of the equivalent setting in Opensearch?

Answer (score 1):

This is an index-level setting, you can retrieve it with

```
GET your-index/_settings?include_defaults
```

You can change it dynamically with

```
PUT your-index/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
}
```

Note that when increasing this setting, it is recommended to also increase `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count`, but since that's a static setting, it's unlikely you can change it in AWS:

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply! I think I should have been a bit clearer in my original post.  I'm looking to change this setting permanently so I don't have to execute the PUT request every month (our indices rotate monthly).  I thinking I might be able to do this by changing the index template to include this setting.  Do you think that will work?

Comment: Yes, you can also add that to your index template and that will work